# CSS link class not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Help please. Can't seem to get my HTML and CSS to match up here... in the page header, I want to include a link which I have formatted in my stylesheet as follows:

```
#header
{
    width: 100%;
    z-index:8888;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);    
}

#header a.nav4
{
    display: text;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: didot;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 60px;
    font family: didot;
}
```

And the HTML I have used is as follows:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class=“nav4”>Stack Overflow</a>
</div>
```

However it doesn't actually appear anything like it should, it is appearing as an unformatted link!

Any suggestions as to the problem?

Comment: Used copy/paste? The quotes around nav4 are not correct. class=“nav4” should be class="nav4"

Comment: change `class=“nav4”` to `class="nav4"`

Comment: Thanks! Seems my mac uses them interchangeably...! Not sure how to avoid using the wrong ones other than by copying and pasting the correct ones...?

Comment: @Samuel — Edit your code with a text editor (Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text are good choices for macOS) and not with a word processor (Text Edit comes with macOS and is a word processor, despite the name).